# Print WPF form directly in RAW

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, printing

I have created a WPF form with labels and textBoxes. I want to have a button and print in raw. I have found this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322091/how-to-send-raw-data-to-a-printer-by-using-visual-c--net but as I can I see I have to save the wpf as image/file first. Is there any other way to directly print in raw the wpf form?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "print in raw" ?

Comment: I want to print using RawHelpers as it is here.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322091/how-to-send-raw-data-to-a-printer-by-using-visual-c--net

My problem is that in this solution I have to select a file and I don't want to print a file but the wpf form that I have. Is it possible to do this? Or I don't know if there is another way.

Comment: You don't have to use a file, you can use RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter() instead of SendFileToPrinter(). Note that the class RawPrinterHelper is defined in step 8 of that URL and SendStringToPrinter just uses the API call SendBytesToPrinter().

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. The point of sending raw data to the printer is that you've already translated your print job to the printer's control language (typically PCL or Postscript/PDF). If all you've got is XAML data in WPF, you _need_ the printer driver to convert all that to the appropriate raw data the printer needs. You should just be using the standard WPF printing API. If you are serious about writing your own printer driver, well...that's a question WAY too broad for Stack Overflow.